# passing input details from one page to another page textarea

Tags: javascript, html

Myself I am beginner and at learning stage. I would like to pass input details from one page (test1.html) to next page textarea (test2.html). attaching both html files.

test1.html(first page)

```html
<html>

<body>

      <form method="post"  action="test2.html">
      <label><b>Customer Name</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Customer Name" name="cname" id="cname"  required>


   <script>
      function ()  {
        localStorage.setItem('mySharedData1', document.getElementById('cname').value);

}
</script>  
      <button type="submit" name='submit' id='submit'>Submit</button>

      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Remember me


</body>
</html>
```

test2.html(second page)

```html
<html>

<body>
<form method="get"  action="test1.html">
<fieldset class="fieldset-auto-width">
  <legend><b><font color="#0000FF">Your Bookings Are..!</font color></b></legend>
  <textarea cols="35" rows="19" id="Requirement1" ></textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
var mySharedData = localStorage.getItem('mySharedData1');
 function(){
 Requirement1.value =Requirement1.value+document.getElementById('mySharedData1').innerHTML+this.value+",                                      "; 
}

</script>    
</fieldset>
</form>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a problem or you don't know how to do it?

Comment: text not displaying in the second page text area. i am trying to get

Answer (score 0):

You have to give a name to the function in both html pages, and actually use the `onclick attribute` of your `button` Submit. I wrote on one page only

```html
<html>

<body>

      <form method="post"  action="test2.html">
      <label><b>Customer Name</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Customer Name" name="cname" id="cname"  required>


   <script>
      function giveMeOneName()  {
        localStorage.setItem('mySharedData1', document.getElementById('cname').value);

}
</script>  
      <button type="submit" name='submit' id='submit' onclick="giveMeOneName()">
      Submit
    </button>

      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Remember me


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function(){
    Requirement1.value =Requirement1.value+document.getElementById('mySharedData1').innerHTML+this.value+",                                      "; 
}
```

This should be:

```
function getValue() {
  var value = localStorage.getItem('mySharedData1');
  document.getElementById('Requirement1').innerHTML = value;
}
```

Comment: how can i invoke "getvalue()" function??

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a function and invoke that function on click submit.

```
<form>
    <label>
        <b>Customer Name</b>
    </label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Customer Name" name="cname" id="cname" required>


    <script>

        function setValue() {
            localStorage.setItem('mySharedData1', document.getElementById('cname').value);

        }
    </script>
    <button type="submit" name='submit' id='submit' onClick="setValue()">Submit</button>

    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Remember me
```

Comment: To check if its set in localStorage or not . You can type localStorage.mySharedData1

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately still i am not getting the result. pls tell me where to type localStorage.mySharedData1??

Comment: console window . To open console window you can press f12 or in some case Ctrl+Alt+I . Then in the console window you can type localStorage to see all the local state saved in the site. And type localStorage.mySharedData1 to see all state available in that object.